# Tailwind align anchor tag to center of screen?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

unfortunately i cant find a solution for my problem.

I want this anchor tag to be in the center of the screen, but the anchor tag is sticking to the left side.

```
<div class="background">
  <Navbar/>
    <p class="text-center text-6xl text-white pt-32 pb-20">Describe what happended and send an email to :</p>
    <a class="text-center text-[64px] text-[#0066CC] font-bold font-['Inter']" href="mailto:test@test.com">test@test.com</a> </div>)}
```

The p tag is centered perfectly to the middle but the anchor tag isnt?

What is the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why this happens

Anchor tag `a` is `display: inline` by default. Paragraph tag `p` is `display: block` by default.

Margins are not supported on inline elements.

### Quick (bad) fix

Add `block` to classes

```
<p class="text-center">test</p>
<a class="block text-center">test</a>
```

> NOTE: the anchor tag will fill the available horizontal space. Hence the space to the left and right of the link will behave as a link. This might not be desireable. [See this example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/gpcFot1N4z)

[image: Example of the problem]

### The better solution

I recommend wrapping the anchor in a paragraph instead:

```
<p class="text-center">test</p>
<p class="text-center">
  <a href="#">test</a>
</p>
```